# finding a row which has several ids separated by comma MYSQL

Tags: mysql

data structure of the table is like that

```
ID    ids
---   ----
 2    3432,545,65454
 3    654,3333223,54333
 4    547432
```

I want to find a row for example which has 545, what kinda query should i write?
maybe find_in_set can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [return all results from a mysql row seperated by commas matching a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987552/return-all-results-from-a-mysql-row-seperated-by-commas-matching-a-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT ID, ids
FROM yourtable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('545', ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FIND_IN_SET in one way.

Another way is

```
select * from tablename
where  ids like '545'
OR ids like '545,%'
OR ids like '%,545'
OR ids like '%,545,%'
```